# Guitar Hero Aerosmith PC not working with GH World Tour PC bundle guitar

Tags: pc, controllers, guitar-hero, guitar-hero-aerosmith

I have Guitar Hero Aerosmith that works well with the keyboard, but not with my wireless guitar that came with a Guitar Hero World Tour PC bundle. It works well with Guitar Hero 3 and Guitar Hero World Tour, both PC versions, but not Guitar Hero Aerosmith PC. Do I have to install a patch or something to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use "Xpadder", it is a software that detects all the buttons of a projection device or hardware, then asignas to each button found a key on the keyboard (obviously). In any case, there are many tutorials to configure XPADDER on Youtube. It is considered a small keyboard in the GHA game configuration.